# Histogram of an array of values in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have a matrix of 630 values (values range from `0-35`)...

I want to find the most frequently occurring value in this matrix. So how do I write a histogram for this? Also is there any other way that I can find the most frequently occurring value (I don't want to use counters as i will need 36 counters and My code would become very inefficient)

..Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) with a Mat of size 1xN, where N is 630 in your case.

I don't understand your argument against counters. To build the histogram, you must use counters anyway. There are ways to make counting very efficient.

**OR**

Assuming your image is a cv::Mat variable `im` with size `1x630` and type `CV_8UC1`, try:

```
std::vector<int> counts(36, 0);
for (int c = 0; c < 630; c++)
    counts.at(im.at<unsigned char>(1, c)) += 1;
std::cout << "Most frequently occuring value: " << std::max_element(counts);
```

This uses counting, but will not take more than 0.1ms on an average PC.

Comment: But I would have to use counter1++,counter2++ and so on ....counter35++...which would be very inefficient??

Comment: That's pretty much what a histogram is.  When you want to refer to set of values like counter1, counter2, etc, we call that an array, so we get counter[1], counter[2], etc.  But now since they're stored in an array, we don't need to refer to them with `if` statements, we can just use our pixel value directly as the array index.  counter[pixelValue]++.  Voila, a histogram.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it manually?

```
Mat myimage(cvSize(1,638), CV_8U);
randn(myimage, Scalar::all(128), Scalar::all(20)); //Random fill
vector<int> histogram(256);
for (int i=0;i<638;i++)
    histogram[(int)myimage.at<uchar>(i,0)]++;
```

Comment: @William...Lemme just try this out

Comment: Im not so clear about your code...is votes the histogram that is initially generated..or do i use it here AFTER i have already generated a histogram?

Comment: ok...the naming is clear..Im assuming ill be initializing the vector as :vector<int>histogram(36) as Im using values in the range 0-35